# How to reproduce Material-UI card style

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am studying about Material-UI but I couldn't find in the Demo (example) anything similar with what they have in their website.

My problem is I want to copy this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zqfm.png), so I am trying to reproduce the container (not the content) using the `<Card />` component, but it doesn't reproduce very well, so I want to know if there is a specific component to use.

Comment: If you supply your code, I can tell you how to sort it. Why doesn't it reproduce very well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for a way to emulate the collapsible demo container that reveals the code behind the demos in Material-UI's documentation (and you want to do so using Material-UI components).

That specific container is implemented in the docs site as an [internal component](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/docs/src/modules/components/Demo.js) and is composed of Material-UI components with a reliance on JSS for styling.  It is also open-source, so looking at [the code](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/docs/src/modules/components/Demo.js) should help you.

Here is an excerpt from the render method:

```
  <div className={classes.root}>
    <IconButton onClick={this.handleCodeButtonClick} className={classes.codeButton}>
      <CodeIcon />
    </IconButton>
    <Collapse in={this.state.codeOpen}>
      <MarkdownElement className={classes.code} text={`\`\`\`js\n${raw}\n\`\`\``} />
    </Collapse>
    <div className={classes.demo} data-mui-demo={name}>
      <DemoComponent />
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is a component that is used for demos in the Material-UI documentation.  It is little more than a styled div with an `IconButton`.

The `MarkdownElement` contains the code that is toggled by the code button presented at the top-right of the container.  It is wrapped in a `Collapse` component, which handles the animated transition that takes place when the visibility of that code is toggled.

The `DemoComponent` is where the demo is presented.

All style is handled using JSS, defined in a stylesheet object.

I'm sure you can build this into a `Card` by following this pattern.  It should be pretty straight-forward, something like adding an action to the `CardHeader` that triggers a state change and toggles whatever you're looking to expand.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, that is exactly what I was looking for. I did it with the Card+CardHeader but it just become a huge mess.